# Why does try catch error in recursive function C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I've created a function used to populate a treeview with a targeted directory. However when I try to implement and error check to skip over folders which may have folder permission restrictions I get an error. Why do I get this error and how do i fix it?

Thank you in advance.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace directoryBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListDirectory(treeView1, @"C:\Windows");
        }

        public void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();
            var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
        }

        public static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
            //try
            //{
                var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
                }
                foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
                }
                return directoryNode;
            //}
            //catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vajura It looks like he has an `UnauthorizedAccessException` :)

Comment: The only error is that your catch handler doesn't return a `TreeNode`. Either return one, remove the catch, or `throw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are answering your own question. You get an error because the user account which this function is running under doesn't have permission to access some of the folder.

You should then apply a try/catch statement WITHIN the for loop so if you get this exception, you function will keep on running for following folders.

```
public static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
             //try
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
            } catch {
                // cannot access directory
            }
        }
        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Comment: That's what i missing. I was placing in the wrong place. In the previous snippet where I was placing the try-catch caused the error. thank you